# Is f(++i, ++i) undefined?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I seem to recall that in C++11, they made some changes to the sequencing behaviour and that now i++ and ++i have different sequencing requirements.

Is `f(++i, ++i)` still undefined behaviour? What is the difference between `f(i++, i++)` and `f(++i, ++i)`?

Comment: Who cares?  It's stupid behaviour.

Comment: I guess [tag:language-lawyer] would be apt here.

Comment: oh my.... that's actually a tag :|

Comment: Since the example in [intro.execution]/15 explicitly calls out `f(i = -1, i = -1);` as UB, the answer to the question (for scalar `i`s) should be obvious.

Comment: How many times would this question be asked here???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's undefined behaviour unless `i` is a class type. From C++11 1.9/15:

> Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced.

followed by a note to clarify that this does apply to function arguments:

> [ *Note:* Value computations and side effects associated with different argument expressions are unsequenced. *—end note* ]

Your code modifies the same object twice without sequencing, so by the same paragraph:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation
>   using the value of the same scalar object, **the behavior is undefined**.

If `i` were a class type, then `++` would call a function, and function calls are always sequenced with respect to each other. So any modifications of scalar objects would be indeterminately sequenced; there's no undefined behaviour, but the result is unspecified.

Answer (score 3):

It's still undefined behaviour:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.
>
> §1.9 [intro.execution]

and the order of evaluation of function parameters is unsequenced relative to each other.

Answer (score 1):

In C++17, it's not undefined.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Undefined_behavior

> f(++i, ++i);       // undefined behavior until C++17, unspecified after C++17

In a function call, value computations and side effects of the initialization of every parameter are indeterminately sequenced with respect to value computations and side effects of any other parameter.

Comment: To add to this answer: code `int i = 0; f(++i, ++i)` would result in `i == 2` and `f` called with any of the following combination of parameters: (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)

Comment: [@Revolver_Ocelot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3410396/revolver-ocelot), I think only the calling of `f(1, 2)` and `f(2, 1)` conform to the C++17 standard, as value computations and side effects of the initialization of two parameters should not overlap.